# Can't locate object method "new" via package Bio::Tools::Primer3

Tags: perl

1. Hi there I am still a novice at this. I'm trying to run this perl script called FullSSR https://sourceforge.net/projects/fullssr, by following the instructions in their 'README.TXT' https://sourceforge.net/projects/fullssr/files/.
2. I did everything as instructed by the app developer(s) which included among others, replacing the Primer3.pm file provided in the *.tar.gz file into /usr/share/perl5/Bio/Tools/Run/; opening the config.txt and specifying the path of primer3_core (file) and primer3_config/ (folder); placing the sequence file I wanted to analyse into the FullSSR folder and executing the perl script using the command line: `perl 'FullSSR\(ver-1.1\).p; -i sequence.fasta -m 5`.
3. However, it was to no avail. Instead, I got the message "Can't locate object method "new" via package Bio::Tools::Primer3" (perhaps you forgot to load "Bio::Tools::Primer3?) at /usr/share/perl5/Bio/Tools/Run/Primer3.pm line 497.
4. I am going to try to install/load Bio::Tools::Primer3 with the cpan module (cpanm) and will see if that does it.
5. Perhaps someone out there could suggest a helpful (easy to understand) manual on CPAN?!

Comment: I managed to figure out the answer to my question. I installed Bio::Tools::Primer3 by typing the following into terminal: 'sudo cpanm Bio::Tools::Primer3 --force' to install it. It only works when I used 'sudo' and 'force'

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out the answer to my question. I installed Bio::Tools::Primer3 by typing the following into terminal: '`sudo cpanm Bio::Tools::Primer3 --force`' to install it. It only works when I used 'sudo' and 'force'